# Posting base64 image to php

Tags: php, jquery, image, post, base64

I would like to post a base64 image file in a php script through Jquery AJAX..

I already Encoded it with Jquery's encodeURIComponent() function, then decode it with rawurldecode() function on php when the data is posted.

The problem is, the Php can't be able to save the proper image to png.

I have compared the posted base64 data and the original data, and they did not match. which led me to the conclusion that perhaps the base64 data is too large to post.

Is my conclusion true? and if it is, is there any other way I can be able to post the base64 data successfully?
If I was wrong, can you please enlighten me?

This is the Jquery Script

```
var whereSignatureis = $('.signatureView');

// i got the image from a plugin called jSignature, assign it to a variable data.
var data = signPaper.jSignature("getData","image");
// created an image ddata from what the data returned for displaying purposes.
var ddata = new Image();
// the ddata.src is now the png base64 image
ddata.src = "data:" + data[0] + "," + data[1];
// I encoded the image with uricomponent for safe posting.
var theImg = encodeURIComponent(ddata.src);
// and posted the image
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processes.php",
        data: {img: theImg},
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(r){
            whereSignatureis.append(r);
        }
    });
```

This is the Php

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/images');


$img = rawurldecode($post->img);
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . 'signature' . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? "{$post->img}" : 'File not Saved.';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: url encoding != base64

Comment: please post some code, how you handle the javascript encoding, posting and the php decode

Comment: PHP automatically decodes query strings before filling in `$_GET` or `$_POST`, you don't need to call `rawurldecode()` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that trying to encode to the base64 text prior to sending just caused problems, since the JavaScript URI encoding functions replace all the spaces in the base64 string with plus signs, breaking the image.  I would just remove the `encodeURIComponent()` function entirely and it should work.